# Inconsistent audio characteristic when recording with android MediaRecorder from Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, mediarecorder

For a project, I am building a small audio database consisting of Bluetooth headphone recordings while running outdoors. The goal is to apply sound event detection methods to the data to detect different classes of sounds, such as birds, footsteps, breaths, and so on.
The data collection is done using a custom Android app to get the rawest audio possible and to have full control over the recorder.
Using the Lenovo HE05 headphones, I noticed that the characteristics of the sound between the two types change a lot over the course of the recordings, i.e. in some recordings the lower frequencies are dominant, while in other recordings the frequencies above 3'900Hz are cut off. This corresponds well to the footsteps being in the foreground and the breaths being in the foreground, respectively. (See the two examples below)
Note that the two characteristics occur on the same headphones using the same version of the app and the same phone recorded with the same user running. Other headphones did not show this behaviour (Tried with: AirPods (Pro and non-Pro), Bose SoundSport and Shokz).

Examples:
[high frequency cut-off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh7NB.jpg)  [dominant low frequencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJde8.jpg)

It might seem that this is due to Qualcomm's cVc (clear voice capture) technology that the headphones use, but the characteristic is present from the very beginning and remains unchanged until the end of the recording. Therefore, an adaptive filtering technique leading to this result does not seem to be a good explanation to my understanding.

The Android recorder app uses the MediaRecorder class with a 16kHz sampling rate and a 96kb/s bitrate. The call to `AudioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_SUPPORT_AUDIO_SOURCE_UNPROCESSED)` returns false and thus the `VOICE_RECOGNITION` mode is used as proposed by the [MediaRecorder documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/platform/mediarecorder)

We have got the input that it might be caused by bluetooth or headphone state triggered by a different app. Hence, we tried many different orders of connecting the headphones, using different apps and starting the recording. However, trough all tests no structure could be identified.